# Why doesn't map convey dynamic bindings?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use a Clojure dynamic var to control verbosity:

```
(def ^:dynamic *verbose* true)
```

But the binding I set is not preserved when I call a function through `map`. Is this expected behaviour? If so, why? How do I preserve the binding?

```
(defn doprint [x] (when *verbose* (println "verbose")))
(doprint)
> verbose
  nil

(binding [*verbose* false] (doprint 1))
> nil

(binding [*verbose* false] (map doprint [1]))
> verbose
  (nil)
```

Comment: If you use `mapv` (which is non-lazy), you will see the results you expect.  See also the Clojure CheatSheet:  http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html